# css: make div rounded circle and add border to the 3/4 of it

Tags: html, css

I have such code:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

and css:

```
.circle {
 border-left: 1px solid red;
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;
 border-radius: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

but i get such border:

[image]

how i can achive a straight and rounded border?

i mean something like this:

[image]

is it possible with css?

Comment: Try using concepts and resources from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415651/half-circle-with-css-border-outline-only

Comment: @m_callens i saw it... but seems it's not my solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Svg circles

Creating a 3/4 of a circle with svg is just a few lines of code:

```css
#cut-circ {
  stroke-dasharray: 110;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="cut-circ" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="23" stroke="red" fill="gray" />
</svg>
```

## or css

```css
.circ {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circ"></div>
```

> **comment** what if i have inner span with text there?

Svg circle with text

```css
#cut-circ circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 110;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
#cut-circ text {
  font-size: 10px;
  transform: translate(-13px, 2.5px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="cut-circ" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="23" stroke="red" fill="gray" />
  <text x="50" y="50">Foobar</text>
</svg>
```

Css circle with text

```css
.circ {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.circ span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 70px);
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="circ">
  <span>Typo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah! good idea... but... what if i have inner span with text there?)

Comment: @brabertaser19 that sounds like a new question, **but** i can edit my answer if you want?

Comment: yeah) will be great!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the 3 of the 4 borders to be left, and the 4th to be white, then rotate it with -45 degrees

```css
#circle {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: why the position absolute and margin-left?

Comment: @Persijn Sorry, that was left there after testing