# CSS Split a responsive circle div into halves

Tags: css

I have divs with a border which make them look "circle shape". The last div should be split horizontally into halves with different text, however, still, it should be a circle.

I use Bootstrap and I have no clue how to round half of circle for one div and another div in the responsive design. Could anybody help me out? Thanks a lot!
https://www.bootply.com/0ksNKnSjZT

With fixed size, it seems to be easy [Half circle with CSS (border, outline only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415651/half-circle-with-css-border-outline-only)

P.S. I don't want to use background image if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the percentage value in `border-radius`, and percentage values depend on the elements `width` and `height` and takes the percentage of small dimension(i.e. width or height).

In your case(in the 3rd circle), the height and width of `.bublina` not same i.e. height is smaller than width, thats why `border-radius:100%` is not making it circle.

So you have to use `px` value instead of `%` value here like:

```
 .bublina.upper {
    border-top-right-radius: 300px;
    border-top-left-radius: 300px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
 }

 .bublina.lower {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two circles with wrapper, use `overflow: hidden` to hide half of circle in wrapper. To have round border, use `border-radius: 50%`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .circle:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper .circle.top:before {
  top: 0;
}

.wrapper .circle.bottom:before {
  bottom: 0;
  border-color: red;
}

.wrapper .circle {
  height: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>My Text</span>
  <div class="circle top"></div>
  <div class="circle bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `px` instead of `%`

```
.bublina.lower {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
}

.bublina.upper {
    border-top-right-radius: 150px;
    border-top-left-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this method you only need to change the width and height values in `.circle_holder` css, the rest will fall into place, (A width value less than the width of the text would look weird)

```css
.top_circle {
    border-top-left-radius: 10000px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10000px;
    border-top:1px solid gray;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
}

.top_circle div {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-7.5px;
    width:100%;
}

.bottom_circle {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10000px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10000px;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    height:50%;
}

.circle_holder {
    position:relative;
    width:123px;
    height:123px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_holder">
  <div class="top_circle"><div>Sometext</div></div>
  <div class="bottom_circle"></div>
</div>
```