# Cut a circle into half

Tags: html, css

Can you provide me a suggestion on how to cut this circle into half? Also float them on between left and right.

```css
.hello {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.50;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done purely on CSS making use of borders. Keep note that height has to be half of the width to give the half circle.

`border-top-left or right-radius` is the thing that adds the curve. So adding that extra +10 to it makes up for the space the border(which is set to 10px) creates. That way you get a perfect  semi circle.

Try this:

```css
#hello {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 110px;  
    border-top-right-radius: 110px;
    border: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: 0;
    float: right; /* Change this to left to float it to left */
}
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

I have made it float right. Just change the value to left to change to `float: left;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: isn't this a copy from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415651/half-circle-with-css-border-outline-only? .. it's funny how you kept the border as we don't need them since it's one color circle ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should first make `2x1` Rectangle, then with `border-radius` make it round, but in just to side. see below code:

```
.half-circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

To make an awesome `CSS` shapes you can see [this cheatsheet page](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/).