# circle with CSS (border, outline only)

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a circle with CSS, which looks exactly like on the following picture[image]

have seen resource from
[Half circle with CSS (border, outline only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415651/half-circle-with-css-border-outline-only)

Comment: I don't get it. You haven't a) asked a question b) shown any code and c) you already have linked to a thread with the correct answer.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.